# Why can't I start the Virtual Machine I just built using VitrualBox?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Everything used to work fine, but I haven't been using Virtual Box for several weeks.  Now all of the sudden, I get the following exception when trying to start my Windows 10(32-Bit) VM. **Note** - Things were working fine several weeks ago.  As far as I can tell, I haven't changed anything on my system that would cause this.  The exception details are as follow:

> VirtualBox - Error In supR3HardenedWinReSpawn (rc=-5640) 
>       Please try reinstalling VirtualBox. where supR3HardenedWinReSpawn
>       what: 1 VERR_SUP_VP_THREAD_NOT_ALONE (-5640) - Process Verification
>       Failure: The process has more than one thread

I have been researching this for some time, to avail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone is in the same predicament, I will share what finally fixed my issue.  I found a post during my hours and hours of searching that said you have to enable virtualization in BIOS settings.  I checked my machine and virtualization was enabled, so I went on searching.  At a loss for what to try next, I finally tried turning virtualization off, just to see.  No change,  but when I went to turn it back on, just as a flook I turned Turbo off, and what do you know - All of the suddent I can start my VM.  So the solution, in case it saves someone time:

1. Uninstall Virtual Box (Latest Version)
2. Reboot your machine and enter BIOS
3. Make sure anything with the term '**Virtualization**' is turned on
4. Make sure anything with the term '**Turbo**' is turned off
5. Reboot your machine
6. Install Virtual Box

Hopefully this saves some poor soul what I had to go through to get this thing working.

Answer (score 14):

There is a workaround:

1. Open VMbox manager
2. Run your VM with option "Detachable start"
3. Wait a while and then use "Show" to show the screen

[Detachable start option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQAlp.png)

[Show the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHtSi.png)

My setup:
Oracle VM Box 6.0 running on Win10, 
VM is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I edited the post, maybe this will be more understandable.

Answer (score 7):

**METHOD A**

If you are using [`WindHawk`](https://windhawk.net/) or [ExplorerPatcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher), exit it and re-try.

**Method B** (not much recommended)

1. download previous version from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds
2. install & extensions
3. Try to re-run your guest OS.

Comment: Wow. Windhawk was spot on. How did you know?

Comment: Uninstalling WindHawk fixed the issue for me

Comment: Don't have to uninstall Windhawk, but do have to [do this](https://github.com/ramensoftware/windhawk/issues/25#issuecomment-1364969239). Specifically adding `C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\*` as an exclusion.

Comment: Well thank you good person

Answer (score 4):

If you are using vagrant to boot up your Virtual machine, then in most cases the error is due to improper shutdown of the VM. A fix that worked for me is to execute `vagrant halt` or similar commands multiple times until you have a clean boot.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround 1:

Just increase the RAM size from virtual box settings

Right Click on OS image .
Settings->System->MotherBoard
Increase the base memory

Workaround 2:

Change the Paravirtualization Interface from default to none

Right Click on OS image .
Settings->System->Acceleration
Change acceleration from default to none.

The above one's was basically a workaround , which can work in some but not in all.

The best thing would be to reinstall virtual box with latest version which virtual box has tried to rectify the bug and use the same vdi files which was made by Virtual Box .

Comment: This is a very weak answer.  Of course I tried that.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do these steps:
1. Uninstall the VirtualBox program.
2. In your C:\users\\  might have two folders called ".VirtualBox" and "VirtualBox VMs": Delete them
3. Restart your PC
4. Install VirtualBox again
5. Add again your VM
6. It must working fine!

These steps worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common causes that will cause this type of behaviour is a missing driver (VBoxDrv.inf). It’s possible that due to some permission issues, the installation of this crucial driver doesn’t complete during the initial installation. In this case, you can fix the problem by installing the VBoxDrv.inf manually.

1.Fix the directory problem Press Windows key + R to open up a Run dialog box. Inside the text box, type ‘regedit’ and press Enter to open up Registry Editor. When you’re prompted by the User Account Control (UAC), click Yes to grant admin access.
Once you’re inside the Registry Editor, use the left-hand section to navigate to the
following location: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\system\currentcontrolset\services\vboxdrv

```
After you arrive at the correct location, move over to the right-hand section and 
double-click on ImagePath the path associated should be \C:\Program 
Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv\VBoxDrv.sys 
if not replace with the above path and click ok.
```

2. Install the VBoxDRV.inf OPen location C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\drivers\vboxdrv right-click on VBoxDrv.inf and choose Install from the context menu.
   Then in cmd run command "sc start vboxdrv"
   Restart system. This should work.